# Запрос SQL на максимальное и минимально значения группы последовательно идущих чисел

Tags: mysql

Таблица Table_name_4 содержит следующий набор данных:

```
ID
1
2
3
5
7
8
10
```

Необходимо реализовать запрос, который выведет максимальное и минимально значения группы последовательно идущих чисел.
Пример результата выполнения запроса

```
Id_start    Id_end 
       1            3 
       5            5 
       7            8 
      10           10
```

СУБД MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                     id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) group_num
              FROM test )
SELECT MIN(id) min_id, MAX(id) max_id
FROM cte
GROUP BY group_num;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e16a65020bbc4983ed36d37e7b4b9982)

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!!